# Remove services from upstart

Tags: upstart

I have mysql installed (from repos) on a development machine (laptop) and I don't need the daemon running on every boot.  I've copied /etc/init/mysql.conf to /etc/init/mysql.conf.old and then removed everything following the "start on" line.  However, upon reboot, I can no longer start mysqld through upstart:

```
$ sudo service mysql start
start: Unknown job: mysql
```

This also fails (trying anything at this point):

```
$ sudo service mysql restart
stop: Unknown job: mysql
start: Unknown job: mysql
```

This is my upstart script:

```
# /etc/init/mysql.conf
....
start on
stop on starting rc RUNLEVEL=[016]
```

This is the default script:

```
# /etc/init/mysql.conf.old
....
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on starting rc RUNLEVEL=[016]
```

Everything I've read up until now suggests that this is how services can be prevented from starting at boot-time.  Is there a better way to do this or did I make a mistake in the upstart script?

*UPDATE*: I've moved the backup conf file out of /etc/init and rebooted thinking that maybe there was a conflict but upstart still says `Unknown job: mysql`

Comment: Check /var/log/syslog, it probably will tell you there are syntax problems in /etc/init/mysql.conf. You can also try 'init-checkconf /etc/init/mysql.conf'

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are on Ubuntu 11.04 or later, you can use the `manual` keyword and .override files in /etc/init to disable automatic starting:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo manual >> /etc/init/mysql.override'
```

`manual` effectively removes the `start on` stanza from the job's config.

If you are on Ubuntu 10.04, you can do this:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo start on never >> /etc/init/mysql.conf'
```

The *last* `start on` in the file will override any previous ones, so this should work, though it assumes there is no event called `never`.

Answer (score 0):

From [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1501721#td_post_9416839) post:
The "start on" section needs to be complete and correct in syntax.

```
start on runlevel [!0123456]
```

This line means execute when run level is not in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6] (those are the only runlevels, so this is never run).

Another option is using `chkconfig` as per [this](https://superuser.com/questions/266040/how-do-you-disable-an-upstart-service-in-ubuntu-10-10#answer-266046) post.